# Import DXA R2 TBB's only

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-2.0

Currently I have a clean SDL Web 8.5 CME environment. I want to install only the DXA 2.0 (R2) TBBs without any dummy content (because I want to use DD4T with the R2 templates). I downloaded SDL.DXA.NET.2.0.zip and tried to import the TBBs with the cms-import.ps1 import command with the 'master-only' parameter. I get the following error:

[image]

I guess it has to do with the mapping in the Content Porter packages but I hope I don't have to edit the mapping XML myself and it can be solved with the PowerShell scripts. Is that correct?

**UPDATE**

I think my question above is somewhat unclear. Actually I am looking for an installer or PowerShell script which enables us to ONLY upload the DXA TBBs, like there is for the DD4T templates (https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.TridionTemplates/releases).

Comment: Just to be clear: You are trying to import the TBB's into a completely empty Tridion environment without any publications? I would suppose that you would have created at least a publication for the TBB's to reside in. The Publication(s) would have to be called 000 Empty (parent) and 000 Master. I am not sure but I think the TBBs belong to the master publication. In a nutshell there should be the blueprint structure for the TBBs to get imported to on the new CME.

Comment: Hi @ginibeagha. I already created some publications. I think my question isn't clear enough. What I try to find out if there is a sort of installer for just the DXA templates, like there is for the DD4T templates (https://github.com/dd4t/DD4T.TridionTemplates/releases). I prefer not to import the example publications.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try and parse the additional parameter `-rootPublication "000 YOUR ROOT PUBLICATION"` (similar to your Blueprint). The default root and master publications are 000 Empty and 100 Master. You above command does not include this parameter. Try it out in a test publication before doing the acutal installation.

Possible values for cms-import are documented [here](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20DXA-v10&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-8B8C6D9E-365E-4C2D-90FD-C4BDFA8B12B2.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-EDB49D8A-DCC3-45E7-B809-6A8B377C4FEA).

**Update:** 
Your question was unclear indeed! There is no straight forward way to accomplish any customization, apart from the ones already mentioned in the online documentation. The master-only pretty much gives you only the templates and schemas that are needed in the master level.

You can create your own custom installation package with any exclusions but you will have to carry the prophecy forward for future updates and maintenance. I would not recommend something of this nature but if you would like to proceed, you may have a couple of options.

**Option 1**

1. Run the default MASTER ONLY installer in DEV or a VM
2. Login to CME and remove the items that you don't intend to use in your
   blueprint or higher environments.
3. Create a new content porter
   package and import your custom packages to all environments.

**Option 2 ( an improvisation on 1)**

1. Run the default MASTER ONLY installer in DEV or a VM
2. Login to CME and remove the items that you don't intend to use in
   your blueprint or higher environments.
3. Create a new content porter package
4. Modify the import script with your custom import package

> $importPackageFullPath = Join-Path $PSScriptDir
>   ("YOUR_CUSTOM_-master-only.zip")

5. Use your custom installation to install in all environments with your custom content porter package.

Like I said earlier, you will have to carry this forward for future upgrades. So unless there is a dire need for it, I would advice against doing something of the above nature.

Comment: In DXA 2.1 a `framework-only` option was introduced which gives you even fewer items, but it only works for upgrades. In DXA 2.2, we will further improve this option.

Comment: @RickPannekoek, ah that's sounds like the option I am looking for ;-) Good to know, thank you!

Comment: @Shiva, I was able to import the items by editing the mappings in Content Porter.

Comment: Nice to know @RickPannekoek!